# Set HTML attribute dynamically

Tags: html, vb.net

I'm trying to generate HTML dynamically, in a way that looks a bit like MVC. However I'm trying to achieve this in Webforms.

I managed to pass a list to my aspx page, but using the properties in the html attributes doesn't seem to work:

My aspx page:

```
<% For Each question As WorkOrderQuestionDAO In Session("WorkOrderQuestions") %>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 620px"><%= question.Question %></td>
        <td style="width: 300px">
        <% Select Case question.WorkOrderAnswerTypeID
            Case 1 %>
                <asp:RadioButtonList ID='<%# question.QuestionID %>' runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="-1">YES</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="0">NO</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
            <%Exit Select
            Case 2 %>
                <asp:RadioButtonList ID='<%# question.QuestionID %>' runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="-1">YES</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="0">NO</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">NA</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
            <% Exit Select
        End Select%>
     </td>
  </tr>
<% Next %>
```

So I try to set the ID of each RadioButtonList automatically, by trying to insert the question.QuestionID property. However the error i'm getting is:

> The ID property of a control can only be set using the ID attribute in
>   the tag and a simple value. Example:

I tried:

```
ID='<%# question.QuestionID %>'
ID='<%= question.QuestionID %>'
ID='<%= Eval("question.QuestionID") %>'
```

At this point I don't know what syntax to use. I don't think it should be to hard, but I couldn't find an answer using Google and find it hard to come up with the proper search terms.

The `<tr>`, `<td>` and `<asp:RadioButtonList>` generation goes fine by the way.

Comment: You can set *client-side* `id` attributes in this way, but not *server-side*.  A server-side control needs a static `ID` to identify it as a property on the page.  To put it simply, you can't give a variable a dynamic name.

Comment: @David So I won't be able to retrieve the control at server side later on?

Comment: Sure you will.  Just give it an `ID`.  For example, if its `ID` is "myRadioButtonList" then you can identify it by the page-level property/variable `myRadioButtonList`.  (Or, in the case of nested controls, by finding it in the `Controls` collection of its parent.)  For server-side controls it doesn't create a new instance for every iteration of the loop.  There's only one instance on the page.

Comment: @David Okay, would the best option be using plain HTML instead of `asp:` components?

Comment: If you want to access it server side (runat=server), then for the vast majority of situations you'll want to use the asp controls instead of the html generic (non asp: component) controls because they expose more server side logic automatically.

Comment: Would it be a good idea to create the HTML object in my `vb class` and then pass the controls to the aspx page using a session?

Comment: @Max: There's a very good chance that utilizing session in any way for this would be a bit of a hack and introduce unnecessary complexity and fragility.  What's the actual problem you're trying to solve here?  If you're using WebForms, why don't you use server-side controls as they're designed to be used?  If you want to use MVC, why don't you use MVC?  Frameworks generally work best when you use them as intended.

Comment: @David I agree, but i'm trying to get something solved for an older project. I would like to generate a radiobuttonlist for each question. After the user has filled in the form and clicks the submit button, the values should be stripped from all radiobuttonlists and will be stored in a database.

Comment: One option is to create the radiobuttonlist dynamically. Like,
  RadioButtonList rb = new RadioButtonList();
               rb.Items.Add(new ListItem("Yes", "-1"));
               rb.Items.Add(new ListItem("No", "0"));
               rb.ID = question.QuestionID;

Then add rb to the page control.

Comment: @Dreamweaver Thats what I'm trying to achieve, could you show me an example or point me to an article?

Comment: @Max: Does a `RadioButtonList` nested inside of a `Repeater` and bound to a data source not accomplish this?  It seems like that's exactly what that would do.

Comment: Sure, just writing a small web page to test the above approach, will share soon. :)

Comment: @Dreamweaver I did write something today, that works for me. But am eager to see your take on this. I will share tomorrow.